# What is the English word for "rinconada"

Tags: geography, spanish

In general a "rinconada" is an incoming angle formed at the intersection of two houses, two streets, or two roads.

In geography a "rinconada" is the land between two mountain branches.

In the next image I tried to do a draw of it, the spiral shows the place that I'm referring to, where some houses could be settled, for example.

[image: rinconada]

**UPDATE**: I take the image shared by @Mari-LouA where I mark in red what is the closest place to what I'm asking for, and I have added the translation for "gully": *quebrada*

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the English word for the geographical idea or the houses/roads idea? What is the scale... is it the area between two distinct aingle mountains or between two long ridges? Is it something glaciers made like in Switzerland (hindreds of meters across between two aretes) or is it a large valley? Is it angled at the bottom? Does it have a stream or a river at the bottom? As to houses/roads, where two roads meet is a 'corner' which is the translation for 'rincon'. How do two -houses- meet? is it the angle of two walls?

Comment: In the end it's probably 'canyon' or 'glacial valley' but I can't tell if those are right.

Comment: @Mitch Is the area between two separate individual mountains or between two long ridges. If it is a small area, there would only be a few houses. If the area is large, it could even be a large town, there is not necessarily a river in a certain position. It is not a valley because a valley is a large expanse at the foot of the mountains. It is a corner (rincón) formed by the two arms of the mountain. Sorry for my bad drawing.

Comment: It does not seem to be in general usage where I live, but maybe cartographers use it. I took a look at [DRAE](https://dle.rae.es/rinconada?m=form), and it appears to be the "_Ángulo entrante que se forma..."_...lo que yo entendí  como la parte interior del  rincón".

Comment: @Cascabel Yes, actually, in my question is translated exactly that definition.

Comment: From your explanation, it kinda does sound like a valley, maybe a small valley? 'Hollow' might work. It's a common geographical term used in place names eg 'Sleepy Hollow'. 'cwm', the classic scrabble word, is really a 'cirque' which is a bowl like area that opens to a valley between two ridges that slope down. 'Valley' works for any (not small) size depression between two ridges, from 10's of meters to 1000's

Comment: More than one  image would be nice to help with the geography. Your hand drawn picture is evocative but it leaves one unsure of how specific it is.

Comment: @Mitch .Hunh..and me having grown up not 30 miles from the birthplace of Washington Irving. The comment should be an answer. It sounds a little like what I have heard called a "holler' in other places.

Comment: @Cascabel I'm still very unsure of what Andrés is describing. I don't have an answer I believe in.

Comment: You excluded valley in your first response to @Mitch "because a valley is a large expanse at the foot of the mountains" but my understanding of "valley" is that it's a pretty semantically open noun that could encompass almost any kind of geographical depression. It seems you have a pretty specific type of depression in mind, but I'm not sure there is a specific English word (even a technical geographical term) for your sense of "rinconada"

Comment: I think part of the problem here is that DRAE's [definition of "rinconada"](https://dle.rae.es/rinconada?m=form) which @AndrésChandía has implicitly cited here (in translation) uses the term "Ángulo entrante" which does not really have a corresponding English translation, though Google Translate gives us "incoming angle". Unfortunately, "incoming angle" doesn't really have a meaning in standard geometry, at least in English. It's not one of the "types of angles" in the [Wikipedia article on "angle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Types_of_angles)

Comment: ... and [Spanish Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ángulo#Ángulos_convexo_y_cóncavo) just mentions "ángulo entrante" as a synonym for concave or reflex angle (i.e. an angle between 180° and 360°). If that's the case, and a better translation of the DRAE definition for "rinconada" is "reflex angle formed at the intersection of two ... mountains", then I'm not sure we have a specific English term for that, and the closest term I would use is "valley".

Comment: @Mitch It sometimes happens that words and phrases have no calque that makes sense in another language. This is how we gain loan-words. I once saw someone here (who?) quote the word _bodega_ as a loan-word which does not actually work in Spanish in the same sense. The point is, that we do not seem to have a good word for this concept in English...time to make one, or borrow from existing idiomatic phrases.

Comment: @Cascabel Geography is full of these loanwords for very technical concepts (some from Spanish): canyon, arroyo, arete, cirque, scree. And that's English. Surely other languages have their own niche tech vocabulary with their own patterns of borrowings, not necessarily in one0to0one correspondence with the English vocab. Im; not trying too hard, but I'm sure there's already a technical term for what the OP is starting to describe, but he hasn't described in enough detail yet for me to distinguish it from 'valley'. Also, I can't find 'rinconada' as a geo tech term in Spanish.

Comment: Maybe this comes down to cultural perceptions of landforms— do mountains have "arms," extra land extending from a central mass, or does that appearance reflect that land is "missing" from the main mass? There are many words for land that has been cut away, especially by water or ice: *hollow*, *coomb*, *cirque* / *corrie*, *cwm*, *bottom*, *strath*, and so forth. I do think the vernacular term would be simply *valley*, which is applicable to just about any area of depression between high points.

Comment: Excellent...thanks for the images... which brings more questions! Why did you circle that articular area and not the very similar areas in the picture which are labeled 'valley' and 'gully'? Do you require that there is -no- stream within it or rather that it is not primarily carved out by water? How is a quebrada different from rinconada? Is the area the result of a retreating or melting glacier? Are you thinking of a very particular place or particular area with a lot of these (please name it)?

Comment: Also, does it apply to a lot of similar areas between all sorts of mountain types, low, high, steep sides or shallow, alpine mountains or mountains in a plain? Or does the word apply to a very particular set of circumstances?

Comment: @Mitch Yeah...the red outline on the image confuses me as well...but I think it is supposed to include the ridge behind it. More and more I am starting to think that "hollow" works better.

Comment: I could not find crook applied specifically to geography but it seems to refer only to the curve, while hollow appears as one of the many terms related to valley, and this one does designates the "space between".

Comment: @ Andres, Yes...I agree. You should un-select my answer and choose the answer from @veegeecee. Seriously. I won't be offended, and in my opinion it is the better answer so far. _Hollow_ or sometimes "holler" has more usage.

Comment: @Cascabel 'hollow' is a very very particular usage. While it may be the closest so far, I don't think it is the closest or most appropriate. Also, 'hollow' is not a generic term - it only appears in place names.

Comment: @Mitch _Rinconada_ is also a very particular usage. It is not used in Central America AFAIK . It seems to be a localized usage in either South America, or Spain.. That makes it even more difficult.

Comment: @Cascabel [Véase *rinconada*](https://dle.rae.es/rinconada).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Appalachia, where I grew up, we referred to a smallish valley (hollowed out area) in a mountain range (not down at the bottom of the mountain but between two taller areas which is what the illustration looks like)as a "hollow" which we pronounced "holler".  People settled in hollows because they generally had creeks in them (were probably formed by creeks, actually) and were somewhat protected from the elements, and consequently towns grew up there.

So, country singer Loretta Lynn's famous tune says that she was born in "Butcher Holler", which is a town in Kentucky (technically Butcher Hollow, KY).

The problem with offering this word as a translation is, in my experience, people don't use it much in conversation any more.  It's found more in place names now.  We are more likely to say "5 miles south on Hwy 70" if we are referring to a geographic location.  But if you used this term in my region, we would certainly know what you meant.

Another option might be "cut", which is a passage between two taller areas in a mountain range

Comment: +1 It's still in use in place names and literature. I think this is a better resolution of the question ...

Comment: I have asked the OP to un-slect my answer and check off on yours...our purpose here is not to gain rep...it is to provide a compendium of English Usage.

Answer (score 7):

***crook***

> a bent part of something, esp. the inner part:

Ex. Kids should learn to sneeze and cough into the ***crooks*** of their elbows.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crook)

A *rinconada* is...

> Ángulo entrante que se forma en la unión de dos casas, calles o caminos, o entre dos montes.

[DRAE](https://dle.rae.es/rinconada?m=form)

This seems to  mean the *inner part* of the angle, inter-section, etc.

[image]

The above  description clearly notes the similarity between ridges of a mountain and an arm.

[image]

From *This is Capetown*, by David Briggs

It is possible there is another term in use by cartographers that I am not aware of, but I have heard writers use the phrase to describe small villages sheltering in the protected part  of mountain ridges.

...and just for Christmas...

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, and kind of  Christmasy, _crook_ is also used for the Shepard's and the Pharaoh's stick, except the Pharoah also had a _flail_.

Comment: I don't think crook is used in geography. It is very poetic, but likely would not be understood geographically without context. In English 'corner' = SP 'rincon' is more like a general area 'Why don't you visit my corner of the world' no literal implication of 'corner' as an angle between two meeting walls.

Comment: I will come back to edit this later. I also think "Hollow" and "Fold" can work here...